# Section 5.6 Exercise 4 in Hartl Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to complete exercise 4 in Chapter 5 of the Hartl tutorial and I am getting these two errors when I run $bundle exec rake test:

```
Started

ERROR["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 2015-03-31 09:33:35 +0000]
 test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (1427794415.88s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `full_title' for #   <SiteLayoutTest:0x00000006cee338>
        test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
    test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'

ERROR["test_full_title_helper", ApplicationHelperTest, 2015-03-31 09:33:35 +0000]
 test_full_title_helper#ApplicationHelperTest (1427794415.99s)
ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
        app/helpers/application_helper.rb:2:in `full_title'
        test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ApplicationHelperTest>'
    app/helpers/application_helper.rb:2:in `full_title'
    test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ApplicationHelperTest>'

  7/7:   [====================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.57888s
7 tests, 14 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

What do these errors mean, and how do I go about fixing the errors?

This is my test/integration/site_layout_test.rb code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    get signup_path
    assert_select "title", full_title("Sign up")
  end
end
```

And this is my app/helpers/application_helper.rb code:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def full_title(page_title)
     base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
      if page_title.empty?
        base_title
      else
        " #{page_title} | #{base_title}"
      end
    end
end
```

This is my test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "full title helper" do
    assert_equal full_title, "Ruby On Rails App"
    assert_equal full_title("Help"), "Help | Ruby On Rails App"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> What do these errors mean, and how do I go about fixing the errors?
>
> ```
> NoMethodError: undefined method 'full_title' for #<SiteLayoutTest:0x00000006cee338>
>     test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:13
> ```

On line 13, you called a method that doesn't exist.
See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NoMethodError.html

> ```
> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
>      app/helpers/application_helper.rb:2:in 'full_title'
>      test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:5
> ```

On line 5, you need to pass exactly one argument.
See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ArgumentError.html

See where the line numbers are in the error message?

I recommend reading an introductory ruby book, like http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/ before (or while) learning rails.

Good luck!

Comment: So I figured out that I needed to add
   ' include ApplicationHelper '
into the site_layout_test.rb file to fix the first error. 

As for the second error, isn't def full_title(page_title) passing only one argument?

Comment: Sorry, the bad method call is actually on line 5 of application_helper_test.rb.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What is the bad method call on line 5? assert_equal full_title, "Ruby On Rails App"

Comment: Yes, on line 5, you are passing zero arguments to `full_title`.  It requires exactly one argument.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across the same error when they are going through the Michael Hartl 3rd edition...

I found the error in the app/helpers/application_helper.rb code. I needed to add an empty string for page_title, changing 'def full_title(page_title)' to 'def full_title(page_title= '')'

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def full_title(page_title = '')
     base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
      if page_title.empty?
        base_title
      else
        "#{page_title} | #{base_title}"
      end
    end
end
```